# How to include a dict comprehension in an f-string?

Tags: python, string-interpolation, f-string

Is there any way to use dict comprehension inside a fstring? THe case is the following:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list_comprehension = [v for v in a]
my_f_string = f"dict comprehension {v:None for v in a}"
```

I do not wanna use format interpolation (`"{}".format(dict_comprehension)`). I want to use the most pythonic way to include that list comprehension inside the fstring to be used for logging data.

Comment: If you want to do "the most Pythonic way" then I would propose not to do that inside f-string at all. You got everything as dense as possible, but the readability suffers and no tools for code checking / formatting / etc (eg. black/mypy) will be able to do anything with anything in the f-string. Create the dictionary and format it via `str(the_dict)`, so `f"{str(the_dict)}"` if you insist on using f-strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, of course there is. You simply need to wrap the comprehension in parenthesis `( )`, since two consecutive `{`s are interpreted as a literal `"{"` string.

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
list_comprehension = [v for v in a]
```

This works:

```
my_f_string = f"dict comprehension {({v:None for v in a})}"
print(my_f_string)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> dict comprehension {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': None}
> ```

But, this does **not** work (Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting also helpfully shows that):

```
my_f_string = f"dict comprehension {{v:None for v in a}}"
print(my_f_string)
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> dict comprehension {v:None for v in a}
> ```

Comment: Great! I was sure that the solution was easy. Thanks for the help, hope this is useful for other people too! ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can be simply done as

```
dict_comp = {v:None for v in a}
my_f_string = f"dict comprehension {dict_comp}"
```

Or if you really want to use a dict comprehension inside an f-string then you have to place `{v:None for v in a}` inside another curly braces with *a space* before and after `{v:None for v in a}`.

```
my_f_string = f"dict comprehension { {v:None for v in a} }"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I didn't want to do. I want to do it in the same f_string. @rou_hola wrote what I am looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In this case I prefer `dict.fromkeys`:

```
my_f_string = f"dict comprehension {dict.fromkeys(a)}"
```

Shorter and much more elegant :)

And now:

```
print(my_f_string)
```

Output:

```
dict comprehension {'a': None, 'b': None, 'c': None, 'd': None}
```

Comment: @MrFuppes Sorry, edited, on Mobile and autocorrect.

Comment: This can only be used if all keys will have the same value, right?

Comment: That works for initilizacion, I am doing far more complex dictionaries but the idea is to do it all in the fstring as @rou_hola pointed out. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JussiNurminen Yes, you can so specify the  value as the second argument as well, the default value. For this case this is the.most efficient.